# Is it possible to share one APNS push certificate across different apps?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I have a feeling this could be a super newbie question, but here goes.
I have an iOS app that uses push notification. 
I am wondering if I can use the same push certificate (the p12 file) for building different apps. It would be nice to just use one push certificate and not have to go through all those tedious setups every time i build a new side project app.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, you need to create a Push Certificate for each app you make if you are planning to have push notifications in your app.

The reason for this is because each APNS certificate is tied to a specific application so that only that certificate is verified by Apple to connect to Apple Push Notification Services to send notifications to that specific app.

Here is a simple guide on how to create a push notification certificate.

http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates